# Detecting online status of the browser in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, microsoft-edge

I've tested following code on mobile devices and Linux and it reported the online status changes correctly.

```html
<script>
    function updateOnlineStatus(event) {      
      onlineStatusIndicator.innerHTML = navigator.onLine ? 'online' : 'offline';
    }
    window.addEventListener('online', updateOnlineStatus);
    window.addEventListener('offline', updateOnlineStatus);
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {      
      var onlineStatusIndicator = document.querySelector(
        '#onlineStatusIndicator'
      );
      updateOnlineStatus();
    });
</script>
```

when i use it on Windows 10 with following adapters, turning the wifi adapter off alone didn't report the offline status. I had to turn off vEthernet(Default Switch) and vEthernet(Docker/NAT) as well to get the expected behavior.

[image]

So if the hyper-v is turned on we can't rely on the wifi connection changes to detect online/offline status unless we perform the same connection changes on the vEthernet adapters as well. Is that correct?

Comment: Maybe the experimental [Network Information API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Network_Information_API) will give you better results.

Comment: @Wendelin, I've tested with network information API, it responds Google Dev Tools' throttling changes, but it has still no effect on Wifi status changes.

Comment: Can you please inform us, with which browser and with which version of the browser you made the test on Windows 10? What is the OS build of your Windows 10 OS? It can help to make a test with that specific OS build and browser. It can help to narrow down the issue.

Comment: I ran the tests on Windows 10 Pro Version 1903 (Build 18362.592), Chrome Version 79.0.3945.130 (Official Build) (64-bit),  New Microsoft Edge (Version 79.0.309.71 (Official build) (64-bit)) and Firefox 72.0.2 (64bit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **Navigator.onLine** property sends updates whenever the browser's ability to connect to the network changes. The update occurs when the user follows links or when a script requests a remote page. For example, the property should return false when users click links soon after they lose internet connection.

Browsers implement this property differently.

In Chrome and Safari, if the browser is not able to connect to a local area network (LAN) or a router, it is offline; all other conditions return true. So while you can assume that the browser is offline when it returns a false value, you cannot assume that a true value necessarily means that the browser can access the internet. You could be getting false positives, such as in cases where the computer is running a virtualization software that has virtual ethernet adapters that are always "connected." Therefore, if you really want to determine the online status of the browser, you should develop additional means for checking.

In Firefox and Internet Explorer, switching the browser to offline mode sends a false value. Until Firefox 41, all other conditions return a true value; testing actual behavior on Nightly 68 on Windows shows that it only looks for LAN connection like Chrome and Safari giving false positives.

Reference:

[Navigator.onLine](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/onLine)